# If...then function for button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, if-statement, input

How would I do an if...then statement for this piece of code?

```
  $('body').on('click', '.icon-lock', function () {
        var lockedarea = $(this).parents(0).eq(2);
    $(lockedarea).find('input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],textarea,select').prop('disabled', true);
  });
```

Right now when I click it, what I want to happen happens as far as those inputs becoming uneditable. However I'm trying to say that if this button is pressed, then this happens. And if it's pressed again, then .prop('disabled', false). However as I'm just starting out, I get confused easily when doing this sort of thing.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your current `.prop` with this:

```
.prop('disabled', function (_, val) { return ! val; });
```

Comment: This works VERY well. And it seems to not have the toggle bug that's present with @Colin DeClue solution.

Answer (score 5):

You need to keep track of whether you want to disable it or not in some sort of variable. Try this:

```
var disable = true;
$('body').on('click', '.icon-lock', function () {
    var lockedarea = $(this).parents(0).eq(2);
    $(lockedarea).find('input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],textarea,select').prop('disabled', disable);
    disable = !disable;
});
```

Comment: More prettier than mine)

Comment: Wow! That did it.
Now...is there a more intelligent (shorthand) way for me to have written this, or is that good?

Answer (score 3):

Use some `flag`:

```
var isDisabled = false;
$('body').on('click', '.icon-lock', function () {
    var lockedarea$ = $(this).parents(0).eq(2),
        inputs$ = lockedarea$.find('input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],textarea,select');
    if ( isDisabled ) {
        isDisabled = false;
        inputs$.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        isDisabled = true;
        inputs$..prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```